# WPF can't open Combobox

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I used trigger to show the combobox when selected row, but it can't open.

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" Height="24" Cursor="Hand" 
                            Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxGridStyle}"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Key" 
                            SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ListItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            SelectedItem="{Binding Path= ItemSelect, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsDropDownOpen="False">                                                      
                    </ComboBox>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: Hi, isn't it because of a `IsDropDownOpen = false` plus I do not understand such complexity, can you explain what you want to do

Comment: I want to change from Textblock of a cell on datagrid view, when selected row, it will change to combobox. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: According to your comment I will propose you another solution. 
As you want to display an information (TextBlock) and then convert it to a ComboBox why not simply make a ComboBox that is not activated and that display the correct information. 

Once the row is selected you can activate the ComboBox and even populate it or anything.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I tried that information, but they refused, I still can't solve it yet

Comment: So your team didn't accept an alternative ? Why .